# Redirect back to the site from which I started the "Stack Overflow Developer Survey" after finishing

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I think it would be great if, after completing the survey, it redirects me back to the site, from where I go to the survey page. At this moment it doesn't do anything

[image]

Maybe it designed like that because survey opens in new tab automatically but it is easy to get the SO (English, Russian, Spanish, Portuguese, Japanese) site url by `document.referrer`.

For example in my case it shows https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ and this is correct url

[image]